# Flutter app life cycle callback functions

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am making an application using Flutter SDK but I am stuck because I don't know whether there are any flutter callback methods like in native android activity callback methods.
Please let me know if there are any. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a visual representation of the "lifecycle" of a Stateful Flutter widget.
[image] This is a helpful reference if you're new to the language.